# Conjugacy Classes in Finite Groups

Tags: group-theory

Given an integer $n\geq 1$, it is known that there are only finitely many finite groups with exactly $n$ conjugacy classes.

**Question:** For $n\geq 3$, does there exists a *finite non-abelian group*, with exactly $n$ conjugacy classes?

Comment: Dihedral group of order 4n-6.

Comment: Steve shouldn't that be 2n-6?

Comment: No 4n-6 works for all n>1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $k$ even the number of conjugacy classes of the dihedral group $D_k$ of order $2k$ is $(k+6)/2$. Hence take $k=2n-6$. If $n=3$, then take $S_3$,